# How do I use "Factor" to get this form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Here is the default answer.

[image]

However, I want to get the result which looks like this

[image]

Here is the *Mathematica* code:

```
Factor[Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 4] + Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 5]]
```

Is it possible on Mathematica?

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please provide code that we can copy instead of images ;)

Comment: OK. The code is quite cumbersome in my case.Factor[Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] + 
  Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 4] + 
  Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 5]]

Comment: bios: That is far from cumbersome code! I have edited your post to include it. As implicitly stated in @JohnDoty's answer, it is best to avoid subscripts when using *Mathematica* until you are well-versed in its idiosyncrasies. They act weird. In your case, it's fine, though.

Comment: Another possibility is `Collect[expr, Subscript[x, _]]`. I'm not sure how generalizable this is, though. Are there are other expressions for which you want to do this? Without more examples, it is difficult to give you a general solution (though perhaps the `HornerForm` answer below does it; I don't know).

Answer (score 11):

```
HornerForm[x1 x2 + x1 x3 x4 + x1 x3 x5]
(* x1 (x2 + x3 (x4 + x5)) *)
```